# Need to handle a concatenated dataframe with non-unique multi-index

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

This works:

```
import pandas as pd

raw_data = {
        'type_1': [1, 1],
        'id_1': ['2', '3'],
        'name_1': ['Alex', 'Amy']}
df_a = pd.DataFrame(raw_data, columns = ['type_1', 'id_1', 'name_1'])

raw_datab = {
        'type_2': [1, 1],
        'id_2': ['4', '5'],
        'name_2': ['Billy', 'Brian']}
    df_b = pd.DataFrame(raw_datab, columns = ['type_2', 'id_2', 'name_2'])

    dfs = [df_a.set_index(['type_1','id_1']),
           df_b.set_index(['type_2','id_2'])]

    df = pd.concat(dfs, axis=1)
    print (df)
```

prints:

```
     name_1 name_2
1 2    Amy    NaN
  3   Alex    NaN
  4    NaN  Billy
  5    NaN  Brian
```

If I change the following, it doesn't work as the multi-index key in `raw_data` is a duplicate:

```
     raw_data = {
        'type_1': [1, 1],    
        'id_1': ['2', '2'],   #  <-- changed from 3 to 2
        'name_1': ['Alex', 'Amy']}
```

and the following:

```
raw_datab = {
        'type_2': [1, 1],
        'id_2': ['2', '5'], #  <-- changed from 4 to 2
        'name_2': ['Billy', 'Brian']}
```

As a result, both `Alex`, `Amy` and `Billy` have the same multi-index key `[1,2]`, so the `concat` fails with:

> cannot handle a non-unique multi-index!

But the duplicate data is valid, and I need to concatenate it anyway. This is the result I need to achieve (note that this should be an outer join, the default):

```
     name_1  name_2
1 2    Amy    Billy
  2   Alex    Billy
  5    NaN    Brian
```

How's this possible with Pandas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change `axis=1` to `axis=0`(defualt)

```
df = pd.concat(dfs)
df
Out[52]: 
            name_1 name_2
type_1 id_1              
1      2      Alex    NaN
       2       Amy    NaN
       4       NaN  Billy
       5       NaN  Brian
```

Base on your comment ..

```
df_a.merge(df_b,left_on=['type_1','id_1'],right_on=['type_2','id_2'],how='outer').set_index(['type_2','id_2']).drop(['type_1','id_1'],1)
Out[80]: 
            name_1 name_2
type_2 id_2              
1      2      Alex  Billy
       2       Amy  Billy
       5       NaN  Brian
```

Comment: Changing the axis value doesn't work if I have to join two rows. For example, if I change in raw_datab `'id_2': ['2', '5'],`  then `Billy` will have an index of `[1,2]` so I expect `Billy` to be in the same row with `Alex` and `Amy` but they are in separate rows. I updated the question to be more clear

Comment: @ps0604 can you show your expected out base on the changes ?

Comment: yes, please see the question, I added the expected result (should be an outer join)

Comment: What if I have more than two data frames? will merge work?

Comment: @ps0604 yes , it will work ，I will recommend given the merge key same name.