# Concatinating multiindex dataframe with non-unique multiindex

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, concatenation, multi-index

I have a dataframes dfa:

```
               y   X1  X2  X3
Company Period
1       1      1   2   3   4
        2      3   4   5   6
        3      3   6   5   6
2       1      1   2   3   4
        2      3   4   5   6
        3      7   8   9  10
...
```

and dfb

```
Company Period
1       1      
        2      
        3      
7       1      
        2      
        3    
1       1      
        2      
        3        
...
```

As you can see dfb has a non-unique multiindex. I'd like to concatinate both dfs in a way that can handle the non-uniquness and add the vlaues of dfa to dfb everywhere, where the indexes are equal. So the desired result would look like that:

```
               y   X1  X2  X3
Company Period
1       1      1   2   3   4
        2      3   4   5   6
        3      3   6   5   6
7       1      1   2   3   4    
        2      1   5   5   6
        3      1   6   8   9
1       1      1   2   3   4
        2      3   4   5   6
        3      3   6   5   6
...
```

I have tried the following:

```
dfb.join(dfa, how='left') #results in dfb
dfb = pd.concat([dfb, dfa],  axis = 1, join = 'inner') #raises: ValueError: cannot handle a non-unique multi-index!
bs_df.merge(dfa.reset_index(), left_on=['Company', 'PeriodQ'], right_on=['Company', 'PeriodQ'], how='left') #results in dfb
```

What am I doing wrong?

I saw similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49786769/need-to-handle-a-concatenated-dataframe-with-non-unique-multi-index) but the solution did not work for me

Comment: is `dfb` a DataFrame or just a Multiindex?  In the later case you don't have to join, but `dfa.loc[dfb, :]` should do the trick.

Comment: It is a dataframe but I can just use the multiindex. But does you solution result in multiple occurrences of e.g. id 1 in my example above?

Comment: I just tried your approach and it seams to be working. Thanks! Do you want to create an answer than I mark it as the correct one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reindex your DataFrame with duplicate indices as well and it will just repeat the corresponding rows.

```
In [11]: df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]], columns=['X', 'Y', 'Z'], index=pd.MultiIndex.from_product([[1], [1,2,3]]))                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
Out[12]: 
     X  Y  Z
1 1  1  2  3
  2  4  5  6
  3  7  8  9
```

```
In [15]: df.loc[pd.MultiIndex.from_product([[1], [1,2,1,2]]), :]                                                                                                                                           
Out[15]: 
     X  Y  Z
1 1  1  2  3
  2  4  5  6
  1  1  2  3
  2  4  5  6
```

Comment: My Pleasure :)    )